# Locking Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2013, and have a macro that copies a "master" worksheet to the end of the workbook, once filled in by the user. The worksheet that's copied, is renamed, according to the "master" report number. Is there a way that once the sheet is copied to the end, it can be locked so the user can not make any changes to it. I just want them to be able to view it. I've researched some sample code online, but nothing seems to do what I am trying to do. Anyone have any ideas or can help? Much thanks

Comment: Use Macro recorder to perform the steps and review the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .Protect and .Unprotect properties.  Below is an example sub that protects all worksheets, charts in a workbook and then protects the workbook itself.  Here's [a site](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-macro-protected-sheet.htm) with more detailed info, and it would also be good to review [how items are protected in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6) generally.

```
Sub protectWk(wk As Workbook)
Dim sh as Worksheet, ch as Chart
For Each sh In wk.Worksheets
  sh.Protect ("password")
Next
For Each ch In wk.Charts
  ch.Protect ("password")
Next
wk.Protect ("password")
wk.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I got the worksheet to protect, but all the cells are unlocked. My code is as follows:

Comment: Although the sheet is protected, now all the cells in the specified range shows to be locked, but still available for the user to select. My code is as follows:    `code'  'select & lock cells
    Sheets(strName).Range("A1:Y89").Select
    ' lock those cells
    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
    Selection.Locked = True
    'protect the worksheet
    Sheets(strName).Protect ("Password123!")
    
End Sub `code`          Where am I going wrong???

Comment: Look at Tony's answer. Click on the link "how items are protected in Excel". This should give you all the information you need.

Comment: Thank you @Mitch -- I was writing the same as you posted. Several steps are involved in locking cells, protecting sheets, etc... and you need to get comfortable with how it works in the user interface before doing things in code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I took ya'lls advice and got it. I love this site! Thanks again!